# Connect two versions of one services

Tags: service, microservices, integration-patterns

Business drives me crazy. They want us to connect one application to two versions of the same service. Both versions of the service differe in some properties. In an ideal world it should only be a configuration change to use the one or the other version of the service

Does anybody know a good pattern what could be used? Or any things I should think about?

Comment: Your question is too broad. What is "one application"? Is it also a service, or it's a client application? Does it have state? What kind of relation between the application and the service? Does the service know anything about the application?
Sorry, but without answers to these questions it's really hard to even start answering.

Comment: "one application" -> we provide a backend service for our clients, we do not have a state, the application uses service to receive tickets from it, the service does not know that an application exists, (hope it helps) :-)

Comment: Ok, now I'm confusing. Let's name it next way: consumer (application) and producer (service). As I understood, you're developing producer. If so, then why do you need to worry about consumer? While you support two versions of API on producer side (which is absolutely possible), there shouldn't be any problems for you. It's a consumer side headache how to communicate with producer and which versions to support.